# $(this) selector pointer in jQuery plugin parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

For many selectors set options:

```
$('#fileupload1, #fileupload2, #fileupload3').dropZone(
    'option',
    {
        url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
        dropZone: $(this).find('.dropzone') //Does not work!!!
    }
);
```

Why? Please help!

Comment: Can you explain your question?

Comment: It is self explained.

Answer (score 2):

Because `this` does not refer to the elements in the selector.

```
var $els = $('#fileupload1, #fileupload2, #fileupload3');
$els.dropZone('option', {
    url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
    dropZone: $els.find('.dropzone') //Does not work!!!
});
```

---

If you want to pass to individual `dropzone` to all 3 elements then use a each loop

```
$('#fileupload1, #fileupload2, #fileupload3').each(function () {
    $(this).dropZone('option', {
        url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
        dropZone: $(this).find(.'dropzone') //Does not work!!!
    });
})
```